# Game Stops after If statement

Tags: c++

I run this code but when I reach the edge of the screen, it doesn't allow me to enter a new travel direction instead the console closes down.. need help fixing this please

```
class weapon
{
public:
    weapon();
    weapon(int x, int y);
    int xPos;
    int yPos;

};

weapon::weapon()
{
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;
}

weapon::weapon(int x, int y)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
}


struct Game
{
    weapon Bow;
    weapon Sword;
};

int main()
{
    weapon * Bow = new weapon(4, 6);   // how to add cout to this to show you have the weapon?

    int xPos = 1;
    int yPos = 1;
    char input = '#';


    while (xPos >= 1 && xPos <= 20 && yPos >= 1 && yPos <= 20)

    {
        cout << "Current x-coord = " << xPos << " Current y-coord = " << yPos << endl;
        cout << "Which direction would you like to travel? Enter N, E, S or W" << endl;
        cin >> input;

        switch (input)
        {
        case 'E': case 'e':
            ++xPos;
            break;
        case 'W': case 'w':
            --xPos;
            break;
        case 'N': case 'n':
            ++yPos;
            break;
        case 'S': case 's':
            --yPos;
            break;
        }
        if (xPos <= 0 || xPos >= 21 || yPos <= 0 || yPos >= 21)
        {
            cout << "There is a wall in the way!" << endl;             //how do i make it continue the game after hitting a wall
            cout << "Which direction would you like to travel? Enter N, E, S or W" << endl;
            //cin >> input;     // this whole section needs some fixing
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

The correct solution should return back to the while loop, allowing the user to enter a new input direction for travel .

Comment: You lack a `default` case, That I see.

Comment: When `xpos` or `ypos` go past the limits, reset them in the `if` body.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have reached a wall, the `while`-condition is false and the loop exits.

I would make the modification conditional instead of first modifying and then checking if it was valid:

```
while (xPos >= 1 && xPos <= 20 && yPos >= 1 && yPos <= 20)
{
    cout << "Current x-coord = " << xPos << " Current y-coord = " << yPos << endl;
    cout << "Which direction would you like to travel? Enter N, E, S or W" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    switch (std::toupper(input))
    {
    case 'E':
        if (xPos < 20)
            ++xPos;
        else
            cout << "There is a wall to the east!" << endl;
        break;
    case 'W':
        if (xPos > 1)
            --xPos;
        else
            cout << "There is a wall to the west!" << endl;
        break;
    // and the other two cases...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this fixed my issue. Thanks